# PHP/HTML - Setting a cap on a input using a variable in php?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to limit the amount of an input like this:

```
<?php
$Maximum = 10;
?>
<form action="" method="post">
     Quantity: <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max=$Maximum step="0" data-number-to fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100"  name="Quantity" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But the Maximum would change depending on the database so it could be anywhere from 1 to 1000+ etc. Is there any possible way I could do this just limiting in the HTML or would I have to just use a PHP `if` statement after the number is submitted?

Comment: Do both actually. Javascript is good as the user won't have to actually request to the server. If something is broken, you are always saved, because of the server side validation.

Comment: the input type=number also has a `max` attribute for that purpose

Comment: Are you just asking how to echo a value inline?  Something like this?:  `max="<?php echo $Maximum; ?>"`

Comment: @David the $Maximum will be pulled from a SQL Database due to the quantity, so if quantity was 10, you can't go above 10, etc.

Comment: @PaulB12345: Ok... So are you asking how to fetch data from a database then?  There are many examples and tutorials available for that.  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @David I can do that perfectly fine, I'm just stuck on limiting the amount of Quantity the user can choose from the HTML form manually updating it but looks like it can only be done using If statement which I thought or JQuery

Comment: @PaulB12345: Doesn't the `max` attribute do exactly that?  What's the problem?

Comment: For example David: The stock could range from 1 all the way up to 100+ so I need a way to automatically limit the max attribute to the quantity.

Comment: @PaulB12345: So fetch the value from the database and output that value to the `max` attribute on the page?  You say that you know how to get the data from the database, and you've been given examples of how to output a value to the page.  Sorry, but it's not clear at all where you're stuck at this point or why simply outputting the value to the page won't work for you.

Comment: @David because doing max="<?php echo $Maximum;?>" isn't working.

Comment: @PaulB12345: In what way does it fail?  Is the value not being emitted to the page?  Is the `max` attribute not being enforced in the browser?  Something else?  "It doesn't work" isn't really a problem description.

Comment: @David Sorry I should of been more specific, it just completely ignores the statement like it isn't there at all. E.g It just bypasses the 10 limit.

Comment: @PaulB12345: That's... not really more specific.  Which "statement" is being "ignored"?  Is the value not being emitted to the page?  Is the attribute or element not being created on the page at all?  Is the attribute there but not being enforced by the browser?  Something else?  Please be specific, nobody here can see your screen.

Comment: @David after re-writing the whole code from scratch again It's worked. Thank you for your help and all the others. Accepted AR_HZ answer as it was the closest to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are getting `$maximum` value from the DB. You can try to use `maxlength` attribute. No need to use JS. If you wanna be on the secure side that you gotta do another check on server side with the if statement as you mentioned above.

Try this:

```
<?php $Maximum = 10; ?>
<form action="" method="post">
Quantity: <input type="number" value="0" min="0" maxlength="<?php echo $Maximum; ?>" step="0" data-number-to fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100"  name="Quantity" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: You're confusing `maxlength` with `max`.

Comment: @David ahh!! you are right. But why this answer is accepted then?

Comment: @AR_HZ: I suspect the OP is as confused as any of us, just for different reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [jQuery Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) plugin which have this feature which you need and a lot of other features which is useful for form validation.

http://parsleyjs.org/

here are example which you need http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Also you should have validation whith php, because this way is on client side and is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript code to limit the value. 
In your current code, there is no limit, the $Maximum variable is not used.

How are you going to receive the $Maximum from the database?

Depending on how these style classes are implemented, you can print PHP values inside html code like this:

`<html> [...] the max value is <?php echo $Maximum; ?> from now on [...] <html>`

Comment: Oh, It would just simply be pulled from a SQL Database saved into a variable like $Maximum and I know it doesn't work, just wanted to show people how what I wanted if you know what I mean? Just max="10" would of worked, but I want it to automatically update after if you know what I mean.